# Select difícil com data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select

Não estou conseguindo fazer o seguinte:como retornar o **tempo em minutos ou horas** que um determinado **VALOR** ocorreu na tabela abaixo? Exemplo: quanto tempo ocorreu o  **VALOR** maior que "23" no dia 01/05/2017? e se tiver intervalo entre os registros? por exemplo 5 minutos com valor 23 de manhã e 3 minutos com valor 23 a tarde? Tem como retornar separado isso, ou só o total?

```
 VALOR       HORA
23.77   2017-05-01 21:40:10
23.77   2017-05-01 21:40:11
23.77   2017-05-01 21:40:12
23.93   2017-05-01 21:40:13
23.87   2017-05-01 21:40:14
24.07   2017-05-01 21:40:15
24.07   2017-05-01 21:40:16
23.82   2017-05-01 21:40:18
23.87   2017-05-01 21:40:19
23.94   2017-05-01 21:40:20
23.85   2017-05-01 21:40:21
23.85   2017-05-01 21:40:22
23.78   2017-05-01 21:40:23
24.15   2017-05-01 21:40:24
23.73   2017-05-01 21:40:25
23.73   2017-05-01 21:40:26
23.68   2017-05-01 21:40:27
7.36    2017-05-01 18:40:28
7.34    2017-05-01 18:40:29
7.34    2017-05-01 18:40:31
7.32    2017-05-01 18:40:32
7.39    2017-05-01 18:40:33
7.4     2017-05-01 18:40:34
7.4     2017-05-01 18:40:35
7.41    2017-05-01 18:40:36
7.38    2017-05-01 18:40:37
7.11    2017-05-01 18:40:38
7.11    2017-05-01 18:40:39
7.34    2017-05-01 18:40:40
7.47    2017-05-01 18:40:56
7.54    2017-05-01 18:41:23
```

Comment: Quais serão os critérios de busca? Valor e dia mesmos?

Comment: @Jovani qual o resultado esperado? Me mostre qual filtro você deseja e qual resultado que eu faço o SQL

Comment: O critério será por dia. Na tabela acima por exemplo, o valor "24" ocorreu por 3 segundos no dia 01/05 sendo estes ---- por 2 segundos de 2017-05-01 21:40:15 até 2017-05-01 21:40:16 e depois ocorreu mais 1 segundo em 2017-05-01 21:40:24...

Comment: Seria algo mais ou menos assim select 'contar em minutos(hora)' quando valor = 23  e data = '01/05/2017' agrupar por hora

Comment: @Jovani este caso `7.47    2017-05-01 18:40:56` e `7.54    2017-05-01 18:41:23` seria qual valor? E `23.82   2017-05-01 21:40:18` seria 2 segundos? Você tem controle da gravação dos dados?

Comment: qual base de dados vc usa ?

Comment: @Jovani: Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados: MariaDB? Oracle Database? SQL Server? outro?

Comment: O gerenciador é MySQL...

Comment: @Marlon Tiedt: 7.47 2017-05-01 18:40:56 e 7.54 2017-05-01 18:41:23 seria qual valor? Se tiver o valor "7.47" em todos os segundos entre 18:40:56  até 18:41:23  o resultado seria 27 segundos...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Veja se é este o resultado esperado:*

**1- Encontrar a menor data depois que o valor é alterado. Ex:**

> 23.77   2017-05-01 21:40:12 
>   23.93   2017-05-01 21:40:13 
>   houve alteração do valor, então a data seguinte ao valor 23.77 é 2017-05-01 21:40:13

Código:

```
  (select top 1 
       x.data 
   from medicoes x 
   where x.valor != m.valor 
   and x.data > m.data 
   order by x.data)
```

**2- Encontrar a menor data em que ocorreu aquele valor, agrupando pela última data conseguida anteriormente, e já calculando a duração em segundos entre a primeira e última data.**

Código:

```
         select 
             y.dia,
             min(y.data) as primeira_data,
             y.valor,
             y.ultima_data,
             datediff(second,  min(y.data),y.ultima_data) as duracao
          from 
             (select
                  cast(m.data as date) as dia,
                  m.data,
                  m.valor,
                  (select top 1 
                       x.data 
                   from medicoes x 
                   where x.valor != m.valor 
                   and x.data > m.data 
                   order by x.data) as ultima_data
              from medicoes m) y
              group by y.dia, y.valor, y.ultima_data
```

**3- Listar cada dia, e somar as durações ocorridas por cada valor, tendo assim o resultado esperado.**

Código:

```
select
    x.dia,
    x.valor,
    sum(coalesce(x.duracao,0)) as duracao_total_segundos
from
    (select 
         y.dia,
         min(y.data) as primeira_data,
         y.valor,
         y.ultima_data,
         datediff(second,  min(y.data),y.ultima_data) as duracao
      from 
         (select
              cast(m.data as date) as dia,
              m.data,
              m.valor,
              (select top 1 
                   x.data 
               from medicoes x 
               where x.valor != m.valor 
               and x.data > m.data 
               order by x.data) as ultima_data
          from medicoes m) y
          group by y.dia, y.valor, y.ultima_data) x
group by x.dia, x.valor
order by x.dia, x.valor
```

---

> Obs.: Coloquei um Coalesce na soma da duração, pois se não houver nenhuma data maior que a data do registro, o retorno da duração será null, fazendo com que a soma retorne null também. Logo, o último registro da tabela (por ordem de data) sempre terá duração `0` pois não é possível determinar quando aquele valor mudou.

***Veja no SqlFiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d5edb/46***

Resultado:

```
dia         valor   duracao_total_segundos
2017-05-01  7.11    2
2017-05-01  7.32    1
2017-05-01  7.34    19
2017-05-01  7.36    1
2017-05-01  7.38    1
2017-05-01  7.39    1
2017-05-01  7.4     2
2017-05-01  7.41    1
2017-05-01  7.47    27
2017-05-01  7.54    10727
2017-05-01  23.68   0
2017-05-01  23.73   2
2017-05-01  23.77   3
2017-05-01  23.78   1
2017-05-01  23.82   1
2017-05-01  23.85   2
2017-05-01  23.87   2
2017-05-01  23.93   1
2017-05-01  23.94   1
2017-05-01  24.07   3
2017-05-01  24.15   1
```

Edit: Reparei depois que você pediu alguns filtros e outras opções, tipo: mostrar o turno, e o tempo em minutos ou horas, então...

**Código atualizado e alterado para MYSQL:**

```
select
x.dia,
x.valor,
x.turno,
sum(coalesce(x.duracao,0)) as duracao_total_segundos,
sum(coalesce(x.duracao,0))/60.0 as duracao_total_minutos,
sum(coalesce(x.duracao,0))/60.0/60.0 as duracao_total_horas
from
    (select 
         y.dia,
         min(y.data) as primeira_data,
         y.valor,
         y.ultima_data,
         (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(y.ultima_data) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(min(y.data))) as duracao,
         y.turno
      from 
         (select
              cast(m.data as date) as dia,
              m.data,
              m.valor,
              (select  
                   min(x.data)
               from medicoes x 
               where x.valor != m.valor 
               and x.data > m.data 
               ) as ultima_data,
                (case 
                  when hour(m.DATA)<12 then 'Manhã' 
                  when hour(m.DATA)<18 then 'Tarde'
                  else 'Noite'
                  end ) as turno
                from medicoes m) y
          group by y.dia, y.valor, y.ultima_data,y.turno) x
group by x.dia, x.valor, x.turno
order by x.dia, x.valor;
```

Atualizei no SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/705f6/12 (Obs. O Resultado é o da última query

> A parte do Where, deixo com você.
>
> Coloquei alguns dados a mais no fiddle para ter resultados com turnos diferentes.

Resultado:

```
dia         valor   turno   duracao_total_segundos  duracao_total_minutos   duracao_total_horas
2017-05-01  0       Manhã   10797   179.95      2.9991666666
2017-05-01  0       Tarde   17942   299.033333  4.9838888833
2017-05-01  7.11    Manhã   3       0.05        0.0008333333
2017-05-01  7.11    Noite   2       0.033333    0.00055555
2017-05-01  7.11    Tarde   3       0.05        0.0008333333
2017-05-01  7.32    Noite   1       0.016666    0.0002777666
2017-05-01  7.34    Noite   19      0.316666    0.0052777666
2017-05-01  7.36    Noite   1       0.016666    0.0002777666
2017-05-01  7.38    Noite   1       0.016666    0.0002777666
2017-05-01  7.39    Noite   1       0.016666    0.0002777666
2017-05-01  7.4     Noite   2       0.033333    0.00055555
2017-05-01  7.41    Noite   1       0.016666    0.0002777666
2017-05-01  7.47    Noite   27      0.45        0.0075
2017-05-01  7.54    Noite   10727   178.783333  2.9797222166
2017-05-01  23.68   Noite   0       0           0
2017-05-01  23.73   Noite   2       0.033333    0.00055555
2017-05-01  23.77   Noite   3       0.05        0.0008333333
2017-05-01  23.78   Noite   1       0.016666    0.0002777666
2017-05-01  23.82   Noite   1       0.016666    0.0002777666
2017-05-01  23.85   Noite   2       0.033333    0.00055555
2017-05-01  23.87   Noite   2       0.033333    0.00055555
2017-05-01  23.93   Noite   1       0.016666    0.0002777666
2017-05-01  23.94   Noite   1       0.016666    0.0002777666
2017-05-01  24.07   Noite   3       0.05        0.0008333333
2017-05-01  24.15   Noite   1       0.016666    0.0002777666
```

Comment: vou testar quando chegar em casa hoje, mas acho que é isso mesmo. Só para entender o que eu preciso: essa tabela registra o valor de corrente elétrica de uma residencia a cada segundo....sabendo que o chuveiro por exemplo consome 23 amperes  (coluna valor ), como saber quantas vezes foi utilizado o chuveiro no dia X e por quanto tempo cada vez?

Comment: o sensor que mede isso, é individual, por exemplo, no chuveiro tem um sensor, na geladeira outro, ou fica lá no padrão, um sensor que mede o consumo geral da casa ? eu colocaria uma coluna para identificar o sensor que está enviando a informação, e possívelmente um número sequencial a cada vez que ele inicia a leitura. mas passe mais informações para tentar te ajudar melhor

Comment: tem apenas um sensor que mede o total de corrente, para colocar em todos os pontos ficaria caro a montagem, por ser uma experiência apenas. Mas como tenho mapeado as correntes de cada equipamento, e meu foco é sistemas, estou tentando montar algum algoritmo que com apenas um sensor e os valores padrão de corrente de cada equipamento(que estão em outra tabela) eu pudesse dizer o que está sendo ou foi utilizado em determinados momentos...

Comment: entendi, mas, não ficaria muito correto, pois podem acontecer situações adversas, mas como é uma experiencia, é válido. Teste o código que já coloquei e depois veremos essa questão das vezes que o equipamento foi utilizado

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, vou precisar melhorar a forma como faço a inserção dos dados, pois tenho o registro de 2 meses apenas(minha ideia era manter sempre o histórico de 1 ano), e já são mais de 50 000 000 linhas, então as pesquisas demoram bastante para retornar os valores.Mais uma vez muito obrigado pelo esforço em me auxiliar, ajudou muito!!!

Comment: que bom que ajudou, sobre o desempenho, acredito que seja possível melhorar, lembre de criar índice para as colunas também. Pra iniciar, você pode colocar pra armazenar o turno em uma outra coluna, para que não seja necessário o case, e também a data sem as horas em outra coluna, para descartar o cast