# Como remover Datas duplicadas no sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, data

Bom dia, preciso de um ajuda para o seguinte problema, tenho esse código
[image: TENHO O SEGUINTE CÓDIGO,]

Que me da o seguinte resultado, porém gostaria de remover as datas duplicadas
[image: QUE ME DA O SEGUINTE RESULTADO, PORÉM GOSTARIA DE REMOVER AS DATAS DUPLICADAS]

Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: Poste o código do seu comando sql e não a imagem

Comment: Você quer remover as datas iguais em (HORA QUE FOI DESLIGADO) mesmo que em (HORA QUE FOI LIGADO) seja diferente?

Comment: a situação é parecida, veja se ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/224764/69359

Answer (score 1):

Olá,
Também vejo como um problema o nome do banco de dados ser "Master", não é uma boa prática, mas é possível.

Sobre o *SELECT*, as tabelas **LFU_Float** e **Equip_String** não são utilizadas mas estão na cláusula *FROM*. E as tabelas **TDL_Float** e **TLI_Float** não são ligadas por uma **chave**

Answer (score -1):

O que observei é que não há linhas repetidas mas sim que o tipo de junção utilizado foi produto cartesiano, o que gerou a impressão de que haviam linhas repetidas. Além disso, na cláusula FROM há tabelas que não são utilizadas na consulta, como LFU_Float e Equip_String.

As tabelas estão no banco de dados `master`, que é um banco de dados de controle do SQL Server. Se possível crie um banco de dados específico para armazenar as tabelas.

O problema se restringe a realizar o *casamento* entre um desligamento e o respectivo religamento, que estão registrados em tabelas diferentes. Há algumas formas de resolver o que necessita.

Eis uma solução:

```
-- código #1 v2
declare @DATAI1 datetime, @DATAF1 datetime;
set @DATAI1= convert(datetime, '7/8/2017 7:00', 103);
set @DATAF1= convert(datetime, '8/8/2017 6:59:59.997', 103);

with OffOn as (
SELECT TDL.DateAndTime as Deslig,
       (SELECT top (1) TLI.DateAndTime
          from TLI_Float as TLI
          where TLI.DateAndTime > TDL.DateAndTime
                and TLI.Val <> 0
          order by TLI.DateAndTime) as Relig
  from TDL_Float as TDL
  where TDL.DateAndTime between @DATAI1 and @DATAF1
        and TDL.Val <> 0
) 
SELECT Deslig as [Desligado às],
       Relig as [Religado às],
       cast( dateadd(second, datediff(second, Deslig, Relig), 0) as time(0)) as [Tempo parado]
  from OffOn
  order by Deslig;
```

A solução acima presume que para cada desligamento registrado sempre há um religamento registrado e que o intervalo de desligamento nunca atinge 24 horas (ou mais).